# How to style icon color, size, and shadow of FontAwesome Icons

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

How could I style the color, size and shadow of icons from [FontAwesome's Icons](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#overview)?

For example, [FontAwesome's site](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#overview) will show some icons in white and some in red but won't show the CSS for how to style them that way ...

[image: Buttons and links of different colours, with both red, white and black icons next to them]

Answer (score 547, accepted):

Given that they're simply fonts, then you should be able to style them as fonts:

```
#elementID {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: @David Thomas: That's a good solution. Thank you for posting that. However, I am STILL baffled why font-awesome sometimes shows icons in white and sometimes in black. WHAT IS THE TRICK? As GirlCanCode2 pointed out, the examples on the FA web site show both black and white icons & text . . . examining the elements in Firebug, however, the CSS for specific icons (e.g., icon-info) gets [over]written to be white. Is that really what we have to do?

No icon-white option as in bootstrap.css?

Comment: for changing the color, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color?lq=1) in SO, hope helps someone

Comment: @Ace I know this is old and you might have learned this by now but for others as well that have the question you might want to look into [specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [also here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). The other thing to know is the CSS cascade; for example styles and stylesheets that come after others are applied instead unless their style rule selectors are less specific (as in specificity). So, my favorite practice is to atleast match specifity and put style after to override.

Answer (score 202):

You can also just add style inline:

```
<i class="icon-ok-sign" style="color:green"></i>

<i class="icon-warning-sign" style="color:red"></i>
```

Comment: To me it makes no sense to place a simple color css directive into its own class and bundle it with your css assets. What will you do? `class='icon-ok-sign my-red-class'` ? or `class='icon-ok-sign-red'` ? That makes it less readable and adds a useless level of complexity.

Comment: Using `<i>` tag for icons also isn't the best of practices. Why nitpick then?

Comment: #id can be overwritten by other styles more easily than inline styles can, without needing "!important" - so it's still less bad. - On the other hand, I see no reason not to make it .class-name --- submitted an edit for the top rated question. --- using i for icons is fine, since i unlike em has no semantic meaning. So quite apples to oranges imho.

Comment: Inline comments are bad practice. this is a bad suggestion

Answer (score 141):

If you are using Bootstrap at the same time, you can use:

```
<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-5x text-success" ></i>
```

Otherwise:

```
<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-5x" style="color:green"></i>
```

Comment: subtle but important: the text-success is the text color, not the color of the button face for btn-success.  So if you are wanting an icon to look like a "flat button", then text-success will be slightly different.  I find this is most apparent in text-warning, since it is an ugly yellow as opposed to a very visible orange

Answer (score 48):

Looks like the FontAwesome icon color responds to text-info, text-error, etc.

```
<div style="font-size: 44px;">
   <i class="icon-umbrella icon-large text-error"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: For Bootstrap, <i class="fa fa-warning text-danger"></i>

Answer (score 19):

inyour.css file:

```
    *.icon-white {color: white}
    *.icon-silver {color: silver}
```

inyour.html file:

```
    <a><i class="icon-book icon-white"></i> Book</a>
    <a><i class="icon-ok-sign icon-silver"></i> OK</a>
```

Answer (score 19):

- For Size: `fa-lg`, `fa-2x`, `fa-3x`, `fa-4x`, `fa-5x`
- For Color: `<i class="fa fa-link fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"style="color:indianred"></i>`
- For Shadow: `.fa-linkedin-square{text-shadow: 3px 6px #272634;}`

Answer (score 14):

There is a really simple way to change the colour of Font Awesome icons.

```html
<!-- Font Awesome insert code -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/49b98aaeb5.js"></script>
<!-- End -->
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#00cc6a"></i>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-4x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#00cc6a"></i>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#00cc6a"></i>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#00cc6a"></i>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#00cc6a"></i>
```

You can change the hex code to your preference. 
NOTE: The text colour will change the icon colour as well unless there is a `style="color:#00cc6a"` within the `i` tag.

Answer (score 10):

Using FA 4.4.0 adding

```
.text-danger
    color: #d9534f
```

to the document css and then using

```
 <i class="fa fa-ban text-danger"></i>
```

changes the color to red. You can set your own for any color.

Answer (score 9):

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

```
<i class="icon-thumbs-up icon-3x main-color"></i>
```

Here I have defined a global style in my CSS where main-color is a class, in my case it is a light blue hue. I find that using inline styles on Icons with Font Awesome works well, esp in the case when you name your colors semantically, i.e. nav-color if you want a separate color for that, etc.

In this example on their website, and how I have written in my example as well, the newest version of Font Awesome has changed the syntax slightly of adjusting the size.Before it used to be:

```
icon-xxlarge
```

where now I have to use:

```
icon-3x
```

Of course, this all depends on what version of Font Awesome you have installed on your environment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

Just target font-awesome predefined class name

in ex:

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

CSS

```
i.fa {
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In FontAwesome 4.0, the classes change to 'fa-2x', 'fa-3x'.

Answer (score 8):

Simply you can define a class in your css file and cascade it into html file like

```
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg green"></i>
```

now write down in css

```
.green{ color:green}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to the link
http://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp

```
<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>

<i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car fa-3x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car fa-4x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car fa-5x"></i>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I tried to use the icons directly from BootstrapCDN (the easiest way). Then I downloaded the CSS file and copied it to my site's CSS folder the CSS file (Described under the 'easy way' in font awesome documentation), and everything started working as they should.

Answer (score 4):

Credit: [Can I change the color of Font Awesome's icon color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color)

(this answer *builds* on that answer)

(for the bookmark icon, for example:)

inyour.css file:

```
.icon-bookmark.icon-white {
    color: white;
}
```

inyour.html file:

```
<div class="icon-bookmark icon-white"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the i tag in p or span, then you can use bootstrap css class

```
<p class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Font Awesome 5 SVG** version, use

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
```

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out, font awesome icons are text, consequently you style it using the appropriate CSS attributes. For example:

```
.fa-twitter-square {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: red;
}
```

If, as it happens quite a bit to me, the icon size doesn't change at all, add "!important" to the font-size attribute.

```
.fa-twitter-square {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @gmartinss. I tried ```<fa icon="chess-board"/> &nbsp;``` and ```.fa-chess-board {
    size: xs !important;
    color: red !important;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.228) !important;
    fill: rgba(43, 255, 0, 0.338) !important;
}``` between the <style> tags. While the background color did change to light purple, fill / color & size were unchanged. Size was also unaffected when I changed to ```size: 5px !important;```Ugh!

Answer (score 1):

For Sizing Icons

Both our Web Fonts + CSS and SVG + JS frameworks include some basic controls for sizing icons in the context of your page’s UI.

you can use like

```
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-xs"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-sm"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-lg"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-3x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-7x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera fa-10x"></i>
```

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons

Answer (score 1):

### **This answer is updated for Rails 7 and FontAwesome 6.5.1**

If you install the gem into your project, you will gain access to helper methods for using Font Awesome. This article provides more information on adding the gem to your project:
https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/ruby-on-rails

When using the helper method, you can embed the icon into your pages using ruby code, like so:

```
<%= icon('fa-solid', 'bell')  %>
```

To add a color straight to the ERB helper, you would add that color into the second string. For example if I wanted to pass in the color green:

```
<%= icon('fa-solid', 'bell green')  %>
```

The color will have to be created in your CSS stylesheet first though. This will also work for Tailwind or Bootstrap, but you will include their color flag instead. Since FontAwesome Icons are text, you can change them with the text-color.

**Example of using tailwind to change the color of an ERB FontAwesome icon:**

```
<%= icon('fa-solid', 'bell text-orange-500')  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically change the css properties of .fa-xxx icons:

```
<li class="nws">
<a href="#NewsModal" class="urgent" title="' + title + '" onclick=""><span class="label label-icon label-danger"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></span>' 
</a>
</li>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('li.nws').on("focusin", function(){
    $('.fa-bolt').addClass('lightning');
   });
 });
</script>

<style>
.lightning{ /*do something cool like shutter*/}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply use something like fa-lg,fa-2x,fa-3x,fa-4x,fa-5x to increase the icon size relative to their container

for eg:-

Answer (score -1):

I would not advice you to use built in font-awesome styling like the fa-5x etc; for fear they may change it and you would have to keep chainging your application code to meet up with the latest standard. You simply avoid this by giving each font-awesome class you want to style uniformly the same class say:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-sabi-social-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-sabi-social-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-sabi-social-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Here the class is fa-sabi-social-icons

Then in your css you can the style the fonts using the same css rules you would style a normal font with.
e.g

```
.fa-sabi-social-icons {
     color: //your color;
     font-size: // your font-size in px, em or %;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}
```

That should get your font-awesome fonts styled

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example how to styling font-awesome:

```css
.arrow i.fa {
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="arrow d-none d-md-block">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
```

That's it.