# Changing font awesome element color

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am working on a template that has font-awesome elements.  How do I change the color?  I cant see anything in the font-awesome.css that allows me to do this. The elements are referenced as:

```
<i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the color of Font Awesome's icon color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color)

Answer (score 1):

```
.fa {
color: #000000;
}
```

This changes the color of class .fa in hex. If you want just  tag use

```
.fa i {
color: #000000;
}
```