# how to properly display a font awesome icon in haml

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, font-awesome

I'd like to add the fa-sort icon from font-awesome to a rails application. I'm using bootstrap, and haml, and I can't seem to figure out how to set this up properly. I'd like the sort icon beside this. I tried at the end before the parenthesis closes :class => fa_icon :sort) however, that's not working. then, I tried adding .feature-icon.fa.fa-sort below the table head, and this isn't working properly either. I've added the correct gem, and called it's dependencies in the application.css structure, but for obvious reasons, can't figure this one out, please shed some light. thanks.

```
%th= link_to Org.human_attribute_name(:department), params.merge(sort_field: :dept, sort_order: sort_order)

%th= link_to Org.human_attribute_name(:name), params.merge(sort_field: :name, sort_order: sort_order)
```

Answer (score 5):

What if you use a block for the content of the link? I guess you want the icon on the link.

```
%th
  = link_to params.merge(sort_field: :dept, sort_order: sort_order) do
    = Org.human_attribute_name(:department)
    %i.fa.fa-sort
```

Comment: oh damn, I'll try that out. thanks for looking out, really. i would love the icon spaced nicely beside the link, just not too close, as I'm getting yelled out for it being too close.

Comment: CSS will help you with spacing. I realised I forgot a `do` at the end of `link_to` - hate those errors from haml when you miss a do..... :-)

Comment: do I need to end that do block at the end of each link_to?

Comment: so, even with the do, the application still breaks.

Comment: oh, what you suggested or recommended totally works, I realized it was my mistake, but it's on the left side, the arrow sorting, but would like it on the right side

Comment: and to answer your other question - haml ends the do block for you. This is one of the weirder parts of haml methinks....

Comment: many thanks for reaching out, really. works, but default light blue, where I'd like them the same as the other color, which is a default grey. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: google found this for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color

Answer (score 0):

After fontawesome update icons have tags like solid regular brand and light, solid tag exists for every icon, therefore fontawesome haml **new usage**

> %i.fas.fa-sort

some icon names changed, you can find detailde info [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4)