# Change color of icon Font Awesome

Tags: html, css

I downloaded a theme that has font awesome icons on the navbar section. When I try to change the color of that icons it remains the same.

I tried

```
.fa-home {
    color:black;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Anyway to see an example ? The reason could be your selector is been overriden by other complex selector

Comment: Check via web inspector if the color is applied on the `.fa-home` icon **OR** the `fa-home`'s `::before` element **OR** if its even getting overridden by other styles.

Comment: @DaniP if Nick tried with inline CSS... There should be no complex selector that could override it.

Comment: link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste amm not true an `!important`anywhere could override it or if it's this case too https://jsfiddle.net/5yoqj0pz/4

Comment: You've got this point @DaniP ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply the style to the :before element, where the icon is.

```
.navbarClass li [class^="fa-"]:before,
.navbarClass [class*=" fa-"]:before {
...
    color: #COLOR;
}
```

Comment: `!important` should not be required.

Comment: This worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with theme, it may have defined the color somewhere in the css file. Search for that and follow the classes of icon so you can find where the color of icon is defined. Or put the css class at the top of the file and add an "!important".
Like:

```
Color: black !important;
```

Comment: Don't use !important. Just don't.