# Change the color of an UIkit icon in react

Tags: css, reactjs, uikit, frontend, getuikit

How can I change the color of an UIkit icon. I am using react components.
Specifically, I want to change the color of the divider icon: https://getuikit.com/docs/divider

I have tried most of the answer in this question: [Can I change the color of Font Awesome's icon color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color)
None of them worked.

I also tried wrapping it in tags or

```
<i style={{color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'}} className="uk-divider-icon"></i>
<div style={{color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'}} className="uk-divider-icon"></div>
```

I want to change the color of the icon itself not background or other css, as these are easy to change using `style`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Underneath the icon system lies the svg inserted into a tag, so you just style the svg.

```
.span[uk-icon=*] svg{
    color:black;
}

.span[uk-icon=*] svg path{
    fill: green;
}
```

Of course you can simply add your own class to an element containing uk-icon to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but might help new ones here!

Using uikit documentation format:

```
  <div class="rounded-button">
     <span uk-icon="plus"></span>
  </div>
```

And my .scss:

```
.rounded-button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  
    span{
     color: white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example, I'm using the Star icon:

HTML:

```
<span class="uk-icon" uk-icon="icon:star"></span>
```

If you inspect this you'll see it expands to this:

```
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-svg="star"><polygon fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.01" points="10 2 12.63 7.27 18.5 8.12 14.25 12.22 15.25 18 10 15.27 4.75 18 5.75 12.22 1.5 8.12 7.37 7.27"></polygon></svg>
```

So for example to make a star with black outline and yellow fill:

```
.uk-icon[uk-icon="icon:star"] svg {
    color: black;
}

.uk-icon[uk-icon="icon:star"] svg polygon{
    fill: yellow;
}
```

I'm just figuring this stuff out so if I've made an error I hope someone will correct me, but this seems to be working for me.