# Font Awesome Icon Color different on different pages

Tags: html, css, asp.net, font-awesome

I am using an i class=fa-arrow-circle-left

On one of my pages it is green (how I want). On another page it is black. I'm guessing something is getting overriden for the color. What am I missing?

I looked through the SO articles such as: [Can I change the color of Font Awesome's icon color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color)

How I'd like it to look(green):
[Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFAVg.png)

How it looks(black): [Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ2Pg.png)

**aspx file with black: (note that this did not have inline styling, that is just something I tried in hopes of making it green, but it still shows up as black)**

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="notworking.aspx.cs" Inherits="project.folder.file" %>
```

```
<p><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" {color: green}></i><a href=""> Member Summary</a></p>
```

**aspx file with green:**

```
 <p><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButtonBackToSearch" runat="server" OnClick="lnkButtonBackToSearch_Click" Visible="false"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Back To Search</asp:LinkButton></p>
```

I also looked at the css file but the only thing I see with black is:

```
body {
color: #000000;
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to HTML and CSS and I might be able to help, but I don't know aspx. Could you specify what `<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" {color: green}></i>` gets parsed into (markup wise)?

Comment: Why not define your style rule in your CSS file?
`.fa-arrow-circle-left{ color: green; }`

Comment: @Saltz probably because they want it to have different colors on different pages?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu In the question he refers to wanting it green on multiple places. Why inline style all HTML attributes if you could do it once?

Comment: @Saltz, I see your point. It still makes me wonder why one page has it as green even though I didn't set it inline as green. The page I set it inline as green, is showing as black

Comment: @seesharp You could check using the browser inspect tool if the color property is inherited from another rule made by for example a template framework as bootstrap.

Comment: `{color:green}` inside an HTML element is invalid markup. Unless aspx automatically changes it to valid markup, that's not going to do anything. To apply specific styles to a particular element, you could use the `style` attribute: `style="color: green;"`, though you should first read up on the importance of not having inline style rules in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking trough your submitted pictures and code examples I found the problem.

You probably have a styling rule made for your HTML elements that your icon inherits due to its position inside the p element. For the code example where the color is not green. Is due to a fault in the syntax for inline css. It should be done as follow:

```html
<p><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" style="color:green;"></i><a href=""> Member Summary</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried style="color: #94b04c;" a moment ago and that seems to work.