# how to change colour of font awesome icon \f107 color. ".icon-classname{color: red;}" does Not work

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

For some reason the icon does not change colour to red. It remains white/grey.

Does anyone know how to change colour to red?

```
.sidebar .nav-item .nav-link[data-toggle=collapse]::after {
            color: red;
            width: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
            float: right;
            vertical-align: 0;
            border: 0;
            font-weight: 900;
            content: '\f107';
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        }
```

There are heaps of other questions that do NOT refer to the "CSS Pseudo-elements" which is the type that i am using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the color of Font Awesome's icon color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474452/can-i-change-the-color-of-font-awesomes-icon-color)

Comment: check class name which you have given and this structure  (.sidebar .nav-item .nav-link[data-toggle=collapse]::after)  because you have written parent to child relation

Comment: @Awais, thank you. However that is not using the CSS Pseudo-elements

Comment: @RandomStuff fontawesome icons act as text just like you give color to text using `color` property i behave just like that. just make sure that there is no overriding styles.

Comment: Go into the the inspector and see if there is anything else that is overriding your styles - your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon-classname{
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to work. I think because it is a CSS Pseudo-element

Comment: .icon-f107{
  color: #f00;
}

This is what your suggesting?

Comment: Yes @RandomStuff

Comment: Instead of writing .icon-f107 let say if your using help icon try to use the class name as .icon-help

Comment: If this is not working then there could be a chance of overriding your styles plz check-in inspect tollbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207162/discussion-between-pdssandeep-and-random-stuff).