# Foundation Icon fonts not properly resizing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have successfully gotten my icons to display as links using the 'foundation-icons-sass-rails' gem but they are not resizing when I try either of these solutions in my CSS:

```
.fi-heart {
  font-size: 72px;
 }
```

In my index.html.erb they look like this:

```
 <div class="row">
 <% @pets.each do |pet| %>     
  <p class="button-left">
   <%= link_to pets_path do %>
     <i class="fi-paw large"></i>
   <% end %>
 </p>
 <p class="button-right">
   <%= link_to pet_friendships_path(pet), method: :post do %>
     <i class="fi-heart large"></i>
   <% end %>
 </p>
```

UPDATE: Ended up referencing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272372/how-to-style-icon-color-size-and-shadow-of-font-awesome-icons) from a bootstrap icon issue with FontAwesome and got it working.

```
 <div class="row">
  <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
   <div class="button-left">
    <div style="font-size: 42px">
     <%= link_to pets_path do %>
      <i class="fi-paw"></i>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Inspect your icon in Firebug / Chrome's developer tool and check out the computed tab. Expand that and you'll see where the current size is coming from. Maybe you have a more specific rule overriding the above.

Comment: When I inspect it, I see `media="all"
em, i {
font-style: italic;
line-height: inherit;
}` in my sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, adding small medium or large class doesn't work.  I added the following code to my CSS to make it work.

```
i.small  { font-size: 0.8rem; }
i.medium  { font-size: 1rem; }
i.large  { font-size: 1.2rem; }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 default sizes for the foundation icons `small medium and large` to be used like this

```
 <i class="fi-widget large"></i>
```

if you need to adjust the size more specifically then you will need to add a custom css

```
 <i class="fi-heart custom-size"></i>
```

and add font-size there

Comment: I was originally calling it with the `large` code but thought I still had to edit it in the application.css, but either way I use it, the resizing doesn't occur. If the icons are showing up and working as links, I don't see why the sizing isn't working.

Comment: the large is overwriting icon size its a loading order issue that is why i said add a new css