# How to change font awesome icon hover color?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Currently my html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook wow bounceIn social"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter wow bounceIn social"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-google-plus wow bounceIn social"></i>
</div>
```

I tried doing the following CSS and nothing happened:

```
fa-facebook:hover {
  color: #006b33;
}
```

I'm totally new to font awesome, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `.`.. `.fa-facebook` is a class, therefore the selector should probably be `.fa-facebook:hover`. It works here - https://jsfiddle.net/k5n8755t/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style icon color, size, and shadow of Font Awesome Icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272372/how-to-style-icon-color-size-and-shadow-of-font-awesome-icons)

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the keyword `hover`... I have retracted my close vote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a typo - `fa-facebook` needs the `.` in front of it, since it's a class selector.

```
.fa-facebook:hover { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write-

```
.fa-facebook:hover {
    color: #006b33;
}
```

Since you are using a 'class' you have forgotten to write '.'(dot) before the class name.

If it would have been an 'id' then use '#'(hash) instead of the dot. The rest would be the same.