# font awesome sort icon pointed to right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to use `font-awesome` icon `fa-sort-asc` in color white and want it to be pointing towards right direction

```
<i class="fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

The sort icons point up and down. If you want to point right, don't use the sort icons.

[The Font-Awesome icon list](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) includes ["caret right"](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/caret-right/) which appears to be what you want.

Make it white [as you would make anything white in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12272372/560648).

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to point `fa-sort-asc` icon to right, you can use CSS3 `transform` property to rotate it 90°.

Also, you can use `fa-inverse` class to make it white.

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-inverse rotate90" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate90 { transform: rotate(90deg); }
```

---

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-inverse rotate90" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```