# Adding color to font-awesome in JS script

Tags: javascript, css

Have found a JS code that show a icon from font-awesome, but its white and i'm trying to add a color to it, but can't find the right class to add it on in CSS file.

The JS codeblock is:

```
      // Transportation icon
  var cellTransport = document.createElement("td");
  cellTransport.className = "timeinfo";
  var symbolTransportation = document.createElement("span");
  symbolTransportation.className = this.config.iconTable[currentDeparture.transportation];
  cellTransport.appendChild(symbolTransportation);
```

How can I add a color to "symbolTranspotation" ?

Comment: What's inside the `this.config.iconTable`?

Comment: add color or use css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style icon color, size, and shadow of Font Awesome Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272372/how-to-style-icon-color-size-and-shadow-of-font-awesome-icons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) to add color.

```
symbolTransportation.style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it to style

```
symbolTransportation.style.color = "lightblue"
```