# Can I change the color of an svg which I render through an <img> tag on the fly with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've downloaded an SVG file from Font Awesome and I render it like this:

```
<img src="@/assets/svg/arrow-down.svg">
```

But the SVG renders in black color which is not the color I need. I could open the SVG file and manually change the color but then if I need the same SVG in black color, I'd need to create a copy and change the color to black again.

This is why I'm wondering if I can change the color on the fly using CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42966641/3702797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `<img>` to `<i>` or use it as a `<path>` then you can color it with `color` or `fill`.
read this:
[How to style icon color, size, and shadow of Font Awesome Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272372/how-to-style-icon-color-size-and-shadow-of-font-awesome-icons)

Comment: May I ask how would the transformation from <img> to <i> happen? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: Download font-awesome fonts and use em as a icon not download their svg and use it as a img look at this link, it helps you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHKjsqw0zw8
You can also use icomoon to generate your svg's to a icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible change svg properties when svg is used as **img src**

You can use fontawesome in standard way as font, and you can change icon color.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening up the .svg file up in a text editor.
You can then use the svg code, inline, inside of your HTML document.

It may look something along the lines of this:

```
<svg fill="#000000">
  ...
</svg>
```

change the fill to whatever you want.

Though if you wanted to retain using the img tag, I would suggest using a mask.

For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="icon"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon{
    background-color: *whatever colour*;
    mask: src("@/assets/svg/arrow-down.svg")
}
```